# Is using a synchronised block of concurrent hash map correct?

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

As per my understanding ConcurrentHashMap will allow multiple threads to read and write (add/remove) on the same hash map with out getting concurrent hash map exception.

I have 4 threads and each thread can update the hashmap. I do not want other threads to write/update on hashmap while the current thread is updating it.

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> playerLoginCounterHashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (playerLoginCounterHashMap) {
                    if (playerLoginCounterHashMap.get("testPlayer") == null) {
                        playerLoginCounterHashMap.put("testPlayer", 1);
                    } else {
                        playerLoginCounterHashMap.put("testPlayer", playerLoginCounterHashMap.get("testPlayer").intValue() + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Is this the correct way of doing it? Without synchronised block I get the values which are not correct.

Comment: that code generates an exception for you?

Comment: You need to use concurrent-aware APIs like `putIfAbsent` or `computeIfAbsent` to allow for concurrency. Otherwise if your entire update process needs to be atomic, then the only solution is to take a lock and prevent any other threads from using the map while you're updating, at which point ConcurrentHashMap isn't adding any value for you.

Comment: @DanielPryden putIfAbsent , does not seems to be atomic like computeIfAbsent from the doc though

Comment: @forum.test17 `putIfAbsent` only handles the "put" operation atomically, that's true. So you need to deal with multiple threads racing to compute the same value. The `compute` function, since it takes a lambda, can handle all this for you, but in pre-8 versions of Java you don't have lambdas or `compute` and so you need to do it yourself with tools like `putIfAbsent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's correct (assuming this is the only place where the map is updated), but it's inefficient, since it synchronizes instead of relying on the inherent non-blocking concurrency of the map.

You should use [compute()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) instead:

```
playerLoginCounterHashMap.compute(
    "testPlayer",
    (key, value) -> value == null ? 1 : value + 1);
```

Or [merge()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```
playerLoginCounterHashMap.merge(
    "testPlayer",
    1,
    Integer::sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, note that in a simple case of storing a per-user long counter it might make sense to use [Google Guava AtomicLongMap](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/AtomicLongMap.html):

```
final AtomicLongMap<String> loginCounterByPlayerName = AtomicLongMap.create();
final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            loginCounterByPlayerName.addAndGet("testPlayer", 1);
        }
    });
}
```

The only different thing is that counter starts from 0.